# I am able to ping to my machine IP but getting site unreachable on browser

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, tcp-ip

My mobile and Desktop both are connected to a router.

When I am making a python server from Desktop on `0.0.0.0` on port `6500` I am able to ping it from my mobile (using Termux) but not able to access through my browser, it is showing `site unreachable`.

To confirm that it is not my router issue I also tried the same by making a 3rd party mobile hotspot and connecting both my device to that and still got the same result.

And to my surprise everything is working fine on windows after disabling firewall.

So I tried `sudo ufw disable` and tried the same on ubuntu but still same result (`site unreachable` from my mobile device).

I also tried making server from mobile and accessing it using my laptop and as expected I was able to access it.

So it is confirmed that it is my OS (Ubuntu 18.04) which is creating problems. I tried changinng DNS to Google DNS after reading duplicate questions but none of them solved my problem.

Please help if possible.
I can provide you with any other details you need regarding the same.

Comment: I do not know if `sudo ufw disable` also deletes all the resulting iptables rules.Please edit your question with the output from `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L`. You might need to also flush any existing rules.

Comment: Thanks for commenting but I have already tried that before disabling ufw I allowed all ports bw 5000 and 7000 for tcp

Comment: What you describe is not the same thing.

Comment: This is really great add the answer it worked after clearing iptable rules and running  sudo iptables-save > iptables.bak   ;sudo iptables -F   this ans is not avilable on internet and it can help others so I am not deleting the question you add answer and thank you so much